# SQLite sometimes disregards the value of a column

Tags: sql, sqlite

In some cases sqlite disregards the condition before and operator and just uses the or operators instead which results in too many answers that don't fit because they are not in that imenik table

```
SELECT k.ime, k.priimek, k.naslov, k.tel_st, k.gmail, kr.ime FROM kontakti k 
    INNER JOIN kraji kr ON kr.id = k.kraj_id 
    INNER JOIN imeniki i ON i.id = k.imenik_id 
WHERE (i.ime = 'as') 
   AND (k.ime LIKE '%a%') 
   OR (k.priimek LIKE '%a%') 
   OR (k.naslov LIKE '%a%') 
   OR (k.tel_st LIKE '%a%') 
   OR (k.gmail LIKE '%a%') 
   OR (kr.ime LIKE '%a%');
```

Comment: You need to learn how to use parentheses correctly with AND and OR to get the correct logic, `a AND (b OR c)` is one thing and `(a AND b) OR c` something quite different

Comment: Please learn to create a SSCCE - for yourself (to be able to solve such problems) and for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should add some additional parenthesis *(put all conditions after the `AND` operand inside two parenthesis)*:

```
SELECT k.ime, k.priimek, k.naslov, k.tel_st, k.gmail, kr.ime FROM kontakti k 
    INNER JOIN kraji kr ON kr.id = k.kraj_id 
    INNER JOIN imeniki i ON i.id = k.imenik_id 
WHERE (i.ime = 'as') 
    AND ((k.ime LIKE '%a%') 
    OR (k.priimek LIKE '%a%') 
    OR (k.naslov LIKE '%a%') 
    OR (k.tel_st LIKE '%a%') 
    OR (k.gmail LIKE '%a%') 
    OR (kr.ime LIKE '%a%'));
```